# Understanding array notation (specifically mysql_fetch_array and print_r)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Do functions that print arrays all use the same notation to do so? What is the reasoning for one notation over another? I noticed when using PHP print_r to display an array compiled using mysql_fetch_array, the notation of the array is as follows:

```
Array ([column] => value [index] = value)
```

For example, if this is the table:

```
id fname lname
1 John Smith
```

Then the print_r output of mysql_fetch_array will be:

```
Array ([id] => 1 [0] => 1 [fname] => John [1] => John [lname] => Smith [2] => Smith)
```

What is the reason for this notation? Specifically, why does the value repeat? Isn't that redundant?

Also, can anybody recommend a good resource for a better conceptual understanding of arrays in general? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Associative arrays use strings for the index, numeric arrays use numbers.

`mysql_fetch_array()` creates an associative array containing numeric keys as well so that both may be used to access the array.

`mysql_fetch_assoc()` creates an array containing only the string indices.

`mysql_fetch_row()` creates an entirely numeric array, and is the fastest to execute of these functions.

Answer (score 3):

`print_r` & `var_dump` are for debugging by a developer only. Its syntax is not set in stone, and shouldn't be relied upon. The only thing that matters is that it's readable to the developer. Especially look at the *source* of a html document and you see a more structured formatting.

As for your second question: seems like you did a `mysql_fetch_array()` instead of `mysql_fetch_row` or `mysq_fetch_assoc`, see the manual pages for those functions.

As for sources to learn about arrays: have you tried the [manual](http://www.php.net/arrays)?

Answer (score 2):

[`mysql_fetch_assoc();`](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc) will give you what you want

mysql_fetch_array allows you use

```
$array['id']
```

but either

```
$array[0];
```

[`mysql_fetch_row();`](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_row) gives you only these numeric values and

[`mysql_fetch_assoc();`](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc) gives you only these string values